# Scheme sum of list

Tags: recursion, lisp, scheme

First off, this is homework, but I am simply looking for a hint or pseudocode on how to do this.

I need to sum all the items in the list, using **recursion**. However, it needs to return the empty set if it encounters something in the list that is not a number. Here is my attempt:

```
(DEFINE sum-list
  (LAMBDA (lst)
    (IF (OR (NULL? lst) (NOT (NUMBER? (CAR lst))))
      '()
      (+
        (CAR lst)
        (sum-list (CDR lst))
      )
    )
  )
)
```

This fails because it can't add the empty set to something else.  Normally I would just return 0 if its not a number and keep processing the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go for this:

```
(define (mysum lst)
  (let loop ((lst lst) (accum 0))
    (cond
      ((empty? lst) accum)
      ((not (number? (car lst))) '())
      (else (loop (cdr lst) (+ accum (car lst)))))))
```

Comment: It took me a long time to figure out how this one works, especially with the double lst on the second line. I could only envision a two parameter version.

Comment: You can substitute (lst lst) with (lst2 let), and change each occurrence of lst below that with lst2; that might make it clearer. Basically it creates a local variable let (or lst2) that is initialized with the value of the original parameter, lst.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you use and return an accumulator for storing the sum; if you find a non-number while traversing the list you can return the empty *list* immediately, otherwise the recursion continues until the list is exhausted.

Something along these lines (fill in the blanks!):

```
(define sum-list
  (lambda (lst acc)
    (cond ((null? lst) ???)
          ((not (number? (car lst))) ???)
          (else (sum-list (cdr lst) ???)))))

(sum-list '(1 2 3 4 5) 0)
> 15

(sum-list '(1 2 x 4 5) 0)
> ()
```

Comment: I like the idea of the two parameters, but can this really be done with only one parameter?

Comment: it can be, but the best way that actually will work that I can come up with requires 2 `if` statements and a `let`.  Using the two-parameter version (perhaps with a wrapper function that simply calls `(inner-function x 0)`) is probably the best way.  Additionally, if you have run into tail-recursion yet, the two parameter version is tail-recursive, while any 1-parameter version won't be.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that you need to use cond, not if - there are three possible branches that you need to consider.  The first is if you run into a non-number, the second is when you run into the end of the list, and the third is when you need to recurse to the next element of the list.  The first issue is that you are combining the non-number case and the empty-list case, which need to return different values.  The recursive case is mostly correct, but you will have to check the return value, since the recursive call can return an empty list.

Comment: If I separate the non-number case and empty list case, I was thinking to return 0 for the empty list and '() for non-number. But again, when the recursion is called its going to try to add the empty list to what it accumulated before, producing a vm-exception like this: (+ 3 '()). I guess the only way to do this is with two parameters.

Comment: @rem45acp - good catch - you will have to check the return value before adding the current value.  You probably could combine the "currently at a non-number" case and the "non-number returned from recursive call" case, if you didn't mind processing the rest of the list unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

Because I'm not smart enough to figure out how to do this in one function, let's be painfully explicit:

```
#lang racket

; This checks the entire list for numericness
(define is-numeric-list?
  (lambda (lst)
    (cond
      ((null? lst) true)
      ((not (number? (car lst))) false)
      (else (is-numeric-list? (cdr lst))))))

; This naively sums the list, and will fail if there are problems
(define sum-list-naive
  (lambda (lst)
    (cond
      ((null? lst) 0)
      (else (+ (car lst) (sum-list-naive (cdr lst)))))))

; This is a smarter sum-list that first checks numericness, and then
; calls the naive version.  Note that this is inefficient, because the
; entire list is traversed twice: once for the check, and a second time
; for the sum.  Oscar's accumulator version is better!
(define sum-list
  (lambda (lst)
    (cond
      ((is-numeric-list? lst) (sum-list-naive lst))
      (else '()))))

(is-numeric-list? '(1 2 3 4 5))
(is-numeric-list? '(1 2 x 4 5))

(sum-list '(1 2 3 4 5))
(sum-list '(1 2 x 4 5))
```

Output:

```
Welcome to DrRacket, version 5.2 [3m].
Language: racket; memory limit: 128 MB.
#t
#f
15
'()
>
```

I suspect your homework is expecting something more *academic* though.

Answer (score 0):

Try making a "is-any-nonnumeric" function (using recursion); then you just (or (is-any-numeric list) (sum list)) tomfoolery.