# scheme multiply list items

Tags: scheme, procedure, r5rs

I looked and looked, but was surprised not to find an answer to this question.

In R5RS scheme, how would you write a procedure that multiplies each element of the list with one-another.  If I'm given a list '(4 5 6), the procedure, multiply-list, should return 120.  4*5*6=120.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be able to take an example for addition (such as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151045/scheme-sum-of-list) and trivially adapt it to use multiplication.

Comment: Thanks Greg! For the record I did try searching for an addition one to base it off of.  I've posed a modified version below in case anyone else is looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(define (multiply-list list)
  (let loop ((list list) (accum 1))
    (cond
      ((null? list) accum)
      ((not (number? (car list))) '())
      (else (loop (cdr list) (* accum (car list)))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

`(define (multiply-list l) (apply * l))`

As trivial as it gets. That's probably why you never found the answer: no one ever bothered writing it down…

Answer (score 1):

The "suggested" way:

```
(define mult 
  (lambda (the-list)
    (apply * the-list)))
```

An iterative implementation:

```
(define mult-it 
  (lambda (the-list)
    (let ((result 1))
      (begin
        (for-each 
         (lambda (x)
           (set! result (* result x)))
         the-list)
        result))))
```

A purely functional and recursive implementation:

```
(define mult-rec
  (lambda (the-list)
    (if (null? the-list)
        1
        (* (car the-list) (mult-rec (cdr the-list))))))
```